# Fitting logaritmic curve in a dataset

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have a dataset `archivo` containing the rates of bonds for every duration of the government auctions since 2003. The first few rows are:

```
     Fecha  1  2  3  4  5       6  7  8       9 10 11 12 18 24
2003-01-02 NA NA NA NA NA 44.9999 NA NA 52.0002 NA NA NA NA NA
2003-01-03 NA NA NA NA NA      NA NA NA      NA NA NA NA NA NA
2003-01-06 NA NA NA NA NA      NA NA NA      NA NA NA NA NA NA
2003-01-07 NA NA NA NA NA 40.0000 NA NA 45.9900 NA NA NA NA NA
2003-01-08 NA NA NA NA NA      NA NA NA      NA NA NA NA NA NA
2003-01-09 NA NA NA NA NA 37.0000 NA NA 41.9999 NA NA NA NA NA
```

Every column named 1 to 24 corresponds to a different duration. (1 month, 2 months, ..., 24 months). Not all durations are sold on the auction date. That's why I have `NA`s.

I need to calculate the `NA`s (missing) rates with a log fitting curve for every row that has at least more than 1 value. For the rows that has all `NA`s I just can use the preceeding constructed curve.

I'm aware I could run a code like:

```
x<-colnames(archivo[,-1]) # to keep the durations
y<-t(archivo[1,-1])
estimacion<-lm(y ~ log(x))
param<-estimacion$coefficients
```

and get the coefficients for the first row. Then run a loop and do it for every row.

Is there any way to do it directly with the entire dataset and obtain the parameters of every row (every log fitting) without doing a loop?

Hope the question is clear enough.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(t(archivo[,-1]))  ## transpose you data frame

## a function to fit a model `y ~ log(x)` for response vector `y`
fit_model <- function (y) {
  non_NA <- which(!is.na(y))  ## non-NA rows index
  if (length(non_NA) > 1) {
    ## there are at least 2 data points, a linear model is possible
    lm.fit(cbind(1, log(non_NA)), y[non_NA])$coef
    } else {
    ## not sufficient number of data, return c(NA, NA)
    c(NA, NA)
    }
  }

## fit linear model column-by-column
result <- sapply(dat, FUN = fit_model)
```

Note that I am using `lm.fit()`, the kernel fitting routine called by `lm()`. Have a read on `?lm.fit` if you are not familiar with it. It takes 2 essential arguments:

- The first is the model matrix. The model matrix for your model `y ~ log(x)`, is `matrix(c(rep(1,24), log(1:24)), ncol = 2)`. You can also construct it via `model.matrix(~log(x), data = data.frame(x = 1:24))`.
- The second is the response vector. For you problem it is a column of `dat`.

Unlike `lm()` which can handle `NA`, `lm.fit()` can not. So we need to remove `NA` rows from model matrix and response vector ourselves. The `non_NA` variable is doing this. Note, your model `y ~ log(x)` involves 2 parameters / coefficients, so at least 2 data are required for fitting. If there are not enough data, model fitting is impossible and we return `c(NA, NA)`.

Finally, I use `sapply()` to fit a linear model column by column, retaining coefficients only by `$coef`.

**Test**

I am using the example rows you posted in your question. Using the above code, I get:

```
#          V1 V2 V3       V4 V5       V6
# x1 14.06542 NA NA 13.53005 NA 14.90533
# x2 17.26486 NA NA 14.77316 NA 12.33127
```

Each column gives coefficients for each column of `dat` (or each row of `archivo`).

---

**Update**

Originally I used `matrix(rep(1,24), log(1:24))[non_NA, ]` for model matrix in `lm.fit()`. This is not efficient though. It first generates the complete model matrix then drops rows with `NA`. A double thought shows this is better: `cbind(1, log(non_NA))`.